# How not to change require_relative after moving files

Tags: ruby, require

I have some question about best way to do this:
I have file `framework/helpers/test_helper.rb`
it starts with line
`require_relative '../../framework/app_manager/app_manager'`
After some toughts i want to reorganize `framework/helpers` folder and move this file to 
`framework/helpers/test/test_helper.rb`
After that i must change first line of this file to
`require_relative '../../../framework/app_manager/app_manager'`

So my question is - that is the best way to `require_relative` file, so I will not need to change `require_relative` line every time i move file from folder to folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is not to use `require_relative` at all.

Put directories that include files you'll need to require in your `$LOAD_PATH`, and then just `require` them.

If you change your directory structure later, you just need to change the lines that set up your `$LOAD_PATH`, and not any `require` lines.

This is exactly why to use the `$LOAD_PATH` as ruby intended, and avoid `require_relative`.

http://joshuapaling.com/blog/2015/03/22/ruby-load-path.html

Comment: Almost all code examples I saw before used `require_relative`. Is usage of `$LOAD_PATH` considers as good practice?

Comment: `require_relative` is popular in examples. I think using `$LOAD_PATH` and `require` are preferable. You can make up your own mind!  Using `$LOAD_PATH` and straight `require` is the way to deal with the exact problem you ask -- it's what it was designed to do.  And is what you'll see almost all gems and most other well-written ruby code do, I think. I think people use `require_relative` because it doesn't require them to understand (or explain in an example) how the $LOAD_PATH works, but I think using the $LOAD_PATH is the right way to do it, for exactly the reason you ask.

Comment: Thank you, I try to implement `$LOAD_PATH` usage in my project and look into it. I hope this is not backfire on me